# Why Is My Login System Not Working - Python?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, pyscripter

I'm working on a login system for one of my school projects and I have linked the code to a CSV file that when the user registers it'll save their name and password. However when you try to re-login the result is that the name or password is incorrect, but when I say I don't have an account and make one it works.

```
import csv
import random

# create a list to store the usernames and passwords of both players
players = []

# loop through each player
for i in range(2):

    # ask if the player has made a username and password before
    newUser = input(f"Player {i+1}, have you made a username and password before?").strip()

    # if the player is new, ask for their name and password and add them to the list
    if newUser == 'no':
        newName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your first name?").strip()
        newPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what would you like your password to be?").strip()

        players.append([newName, newPassword])

        file = open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'a', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        writer.writerow([newName, newPassword])

        file.close()

    # if the player has logged in before, ask for their name and password and check if they match
    elif newUser == 'yes':
        verifyName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your name?").strip()
        verifyPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your password?").strip()

        # loop through each player's login information and check if there is a match
        match_found = False
        for player in players:
            if player == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
                print(f"Player {i+1}, you are logged in")
                match_found = True
                break

        # if there is no match, inform the player and ask them to try again
        if not match_found:
            print(f"Player {i+1}, wrong username or password. Please try again.")

# print welcome message with the players' names
if len(players) >= 2:
    print(f"Welcome, {players[0][0]} and {players[1][0]}!")
else:
    print("Error: not enough players logged in.")
```

When I print the CSV file and what it contains it shows all of the names that have been previously registered:

```
'finley'  'fin'  '10'
janet janet123 None
james james123 None
charlie charlie123 None
amy amy123 None
fred fred123 None
summer summer123 None
nat nat123 None
nathan nathan123 None
elle elle123 None
charles charles123 None
juno juno123 None
sam sam123 None
samuel samuel123 None
Tom Tom123 None
Thomas Thomas123 None
charlie charlie123 None
grace grace123 None
natalie natalie123 None
Dan Dan123 None
Daniel Daniel123 None
```

I am new to CSV so I used a google sheet to create the file but then it got opened in VS Code which only shows 2 names:

```
finley,fin,10
janet,janet123
```

It's formatted like:
name,password,score
I'm also using PyScripter for the actual code

Answer (score 0):

When I read your code it seems like you are not really reading the .CSV file but only from the `Players`list. i would try add this code before checking for login credentials. it uses the `òpen` function that reads the .CSV file and then we store that data in the `players` list

```
#open the CSV file and read the data into the players list
with open('ScoreSheet.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        players.append(row)
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to do the job. However now at the end of the code when I print ```print(f"Welcome, {players[0][0]} and {players[1][0]}!")``` It is returning ```Welcome, name and 'finley'!``` Even when I've logged in under different names

Comment: the players list is only being populated with the names and passwords of users who register a new account. When a user logs in with an existing account, their information is not being added to the players list.

To fix this issue, you can modify your login logic to append the user's information to the players list when they log in.

1. Create a variable to store the index of the logged in user in the players list:
2. Modify the login logic to set the `logged_in_index` variable to the index of the logged in user in the `players` list:
3. update the welcome message to use both lists

Comment: Thank you so much I'll have a try with that

Comment: No problem. if you need further help feel free to create a new question and link to it here if needed.

Comment: I have ran into another problem, here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75832822/21389991

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are appending the new user's information to the players list, but you are not reading the data from the CSV file to check for existing users. You may try below code.

In this updated version, the players list is initialized with the data from the CSV file using the csv.reader function. When a new user is added, their information is appended to both the players list and the CSV file using the csv.writer function.

When an existing user logs in, the players list is searched for a match with their name and password. If a match is found, the user is logged in. If not, they are prompted to try again.

```
import csv
import random

# create a list to store the usernames and passwords of both players
players = []

# read existing users from the CSV file
with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        players.append(row)

# loop through each player
for i in range(2):

    # ask if the player has made a username and password before
    newUser = input(f"Player {i+1}, have you made a username and password before?").strip()

    # if the player is new, ask for their name and password and add them to the list and CSV file
    if newUser == 'no':
        newName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your first name?").strip()
        newPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what would you like your password to be?").strip()

        players.append([newName, newPassword])

        with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([newName, newPassword])

    # if the player has logged in before, ask for their name and password and check if they match
    elif newUser == 'yes':
        verifyName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your name?").strip()
        verifyPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your password?").strip()

        # loop through each player's login information and check if there is a match
        match_found = False
        for player in players:
            if player == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
                print(f"Player {i+1}, you are logged in")
                match_found = True
                break

        # if there is no match, inform the player and ask them to try again
        if not match_found:
            print(f"Player {i+1}, wrong username or password. Please try again.")

# print welcome message with the players' names
if len(players) >= 2:
    print(f"Welcome, {players[0][0]} and {players[1][0]}!")
else:
    print("Error: not enough players logged in.")
```

`

Comment: Thank you this did the job as well as the other suggestion