# Why Is My Login System Not Reading and printing the correct names from my CSV file

Tags: python, csv, authentication

I have create a Login System for a card game, however it was at one point working smoothly but now it is malfunctioning. As in when I try to re-login or even try to register as a new player it always returns 'Welcome 'finley' and janet! which are the first 2 names from my file, but they were not the ones I logged in under

Here's the code that I've tried. I am using PyScripter for the code and VSC for my CSV.

```
import csv
import random
import keyboard



# create a list to store the usernames and passwords of both players
players = []
key = True
# read existing users from the CSV file
with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        players.append(row)

# loop through each player
for i in range(2):

    # ask if the player has made a username and password before
    newUser = input(f"Player {i+1}, have you made a username and password before? ").strip()

    # if the player is new, ask for their name and password and add them to the list and CSV file
    if newUser == 'no':
        newName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your first name? ").strip()
        newPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what would you like your password to be? ").strip()

        players.append([newName, newPassword])

        with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([newName, newPassword])

    # if the player has logged in before, ask for their name and password and check if they match
    elif newUser == 'yes':
        verifyName = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your name? ").strip()
        verifyPassword = input(f"Player {i+1}, what is your password? ").strip()

        # loop through each player's login information and check if there is a match
        match_found = False
        for player in players:
            if player == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
                print(f"Player {i+1}, you are logged in")
                match_found = True
                break

        # if there is no match, inform the player and ask them to try again
        if not match_found:
            print(f"Player {i+1}, wrong username or password. Please try again.")

# print welcome message with the players' names
if len(players) >= 0:
    print(f"Welcome, {players[0][0]} and {players[1][0]}!")
    access = True
else:
    print("Error: not enough players logged in.")
```

Here is what it's returning:

Player 1, have you made a username and password before? yes
Player 1, what is your name? janet
Player 1, what is your password? janet123
Player 1, you are logged in
Player 2, have you made a username and password before? yes
Player 2, what is your name? juno
Player 2, what is your password? juno123
Player 2, you are logged in
Welcome, 'finley' and janet!

I've ran some tests to check the logic, and matching capabilities and they still seem to work

```
with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   for row in reader:
       print(f"CSV row: {row}")
       if row == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
           print(f"You are logged in with username: {verifyName} and password: {verifyPassword}")
           match_found = True
           break

print(f"Input username: {verifyName}")
print(f"Input password: {verifyPassword}")




with open('ScoreSheet.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['name'], row['password'], row['score'])


with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(type(row))  # add this line to check the data type
        if row == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
            print('You are logged in')
            match_found = True
            break



with open('ScoreSheet.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)  # add this line to check the rows
        if row == [verifyName, verifyPassword]:
            print('You are logged in')
            match_found = True
            break
        else:
            print(f"Row {row} does not match {verifyName} and {verifyPassword}")
```

They Return:

```
CSV row: ['name', 'password', 'score']
CSV row: ["'finley'", " 'fin'", " '10'"]
CSV row: ['janet', 'janet123']
CSV row: ['james', 'james123']
CSV row: ['charlie', 'charlie123']
CSV row: ['amy', 'amy123']
CSV row: ['fred', 'fred123']
CSV row: ['summer', 'summer123']
CSV row: ['nat', 'nat123']
CSV row: ['nathan', 'nathan123']
CSV row: ['elle', 'elle123']
CSV row: ['charles', 'charles123']
CSV row: ['juno', 'juno123']
You are logged in with username: juno and password: juno123
Input username: juno
Input password: juno123
'finley'  'fin'  '10'
janet janet123 None
james james123 None
charlie charlie123 None
amy amy123 None
fred fred123 None
summer summer123 None
nat nat123 None
nathan nathan123 None
elle elle123 None
charles charles123 None
juno juno123 None
sam sam123 None
samuel samuel123 None
Tom Tom123 None
Thomas Thomas123 None
charlie charlie123 None
grace grace123 None
natalie natalie123 None
Dan Dan123 None
Daniel Daniel123 None
nathaniel nathaniel123 None
lisa lisa123 None
joel joel123 None
jake jake123 None
jane jane123 None
james james123 None
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
You are logged in
['name', 'password', 'score']
Row ['name', 'password', 'score'] does not match juno and juno123
["'finley'", " 'fin'", " '10'"]
Row ["'finley'", " 'fin'", " '10'"] does not match juno and juno123
['janet', 'janet123']
Row ['janet', 'janet123'] does not match juno and juno123
['james', 'james123']
Row ['james', 'james123'] does not match juno and juno123
['charlie', 'charlie123']
Row ['charlie', 'charlie123'] does not match juno and juno123
['amy', 'amy123']
Row ['amy', 'amy123'] does not match juno and juno123
['fred', 'fred123']
Row ['fred', 'fred123'] does not match juno and juno123
['summer', 'summer123']
Row ['summer', 'summer123'] does not match juno and juno123
['nat', 'nat123']
Row ['nat', 'nat123'] does not match juno and juno123
['nathan', 'nathan123']
Row ['nathan', 'nathan123'] does not match juno and juno123
['elle', 'elle123']
Row ['elle', 'elle123'] does not match juno and juno123
['charles', 'charles123']
Row ['charles', 'charles123'] does not match juno and juno123
['juno', 'juno123']
You are logged in
Here is your card 'finley': Yellow 5
Here is your card janet: Yellow 1
```

Comment: please provide the csv file.

Comment: also if you are reading a csv into list, it would be simpler (fewer code lines) to use `pandas.read_csv()`...

Comment: Using Pandas just to get a slightly more convenient CSV API is huge overkill.

Comment: Explain why this line would ever print anything other than the two first lines from the file: `print(f"Welcome, {players[0][0]} and {players[1][0]}!")`.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know. Why don't you help instead of being so arrogant? I am trying to get that to refer to the list at the top and the registered names should go to that list when logging in.